# Creating a livestream website

Tags: django, video-streaming, video-capture, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

We already have a functionality of Video uploading in our webapplication[built using python with Django framework]. Now we are in the process of building a livestream site where people are able to use their webcam to record the live event and it's live streamed to different participants at the sametime.

I am wondering if somebody has any idea of how to go about building a functionality like this or any pointers that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I sort of looked into this same question a while ago. The dominant solution seems to be [Adobes Flash Media Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Media_Server). It is closed source of course and quite pricey. There are [companies](http://www.influxis.com/) who run it as a service, lowering the cost of entry. And there are open source contenders, the main one being  [Red5](http://www.red5.org/), which of course also relies on flash being available on the client side.

In the future we'll probably see viable HTML5 alternatives but if you're doing something right now my feeling is that the flash route is the simplest solution and has the largest install base.

Comment: thanks oivvio, I too read about using the FMS or Wowza. I would try out and share my experiences.

Comment: with WebRTC it seems more interesting things would be happening.

Answer (score 1):

I did a video vlc record with python and it was quite simple. VLC have a stream recorder and as I know you could launch a vlc stream with a simple python code who manage the video ans the stream. I think all you need is to manage the sources and then, doing a small script who takes care about the vlc stream.

VLC stream will be launch on a different port, so I think you've to search a good server.

see vlc docs : 
https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Check **VLC** or **Flumotion**...
Probably **Photolab** as well..
The latter one doesn't support audio...
Gee

Comment: @ovivio Yeah flash's not too bad but its propriatary stuff. Who wants to use that if not really necessary?